# RegEx Print a Custom Line

Tags: regex, lua

This is an example of my code with Lua

```
local p = io.popen('nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com', 'r');
local output = p:read('a+');
p:close();
print (output)
```

Whose output is something like the following:

**Server:  resolver1.opendns.com**
**Address:  208.67.222.222**

**Name:    myip.opendns.com**
**Address:  85.185.195.150**

But I want only ***Address:  85.185.195.150*** to be printed
How can I do this?

Comment: Check out this answer here: https://superuser.com/a/1225275/146004

Answer (score 0):

#### Hello

A regular expression and tail last line for the desired output.

```
local p = io.popen('nslookup hostname resolver | grep -o -E "^Address:.([0-9.]{2,4}){4}$" | tail -n1', 'r');
```

But you dont need a regular expression. Try...

```
local p = io.popen('nslookup hostname resolver | tail -n2', 'r');
```